# spark-shell load existing hive table by partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-shell

In `spark-shell`, how do I load an existing Hive table, but only one of its partitions?

```
val df = spark.read.format("orc").load("mytable")
```

I was looking for a way so it only loads one particular partition of this table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way in `spark.read.format` but you can use `where` condition

```
val df = spark.read.format("orc").load("mytable").where(yourparitioncolumn)
```

unless ***until you perform an action nothing is loaded***, since `load` (pointing to your orc file location ) is just a func in `DataFrameReader` like below it doesnt load until actioned.

see here [DataFrameReader](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L224)

```
 def load(paths: String*): DataFrame = {
...
}
```

In above  code i.e. `spark.read`.... `where` is just `where` condition when you specify this, again data wont be loaded immediately :-)

when you say `df.count` then your parition column will be appled on data path of orc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function available in Spark API to load only partition directory, but other way around this is partiton directory is nothing but column in where clause, here you can right simple sql query with partition column in where clause which will read data only from partition directoty. See if that will works for you.

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <partition_col_name> = <expected_value>")
```